# How to optimize the pagination query?

Tags: php, cakephp, optimization

This is completely optimization question, I have a pagination query like that

```
$this->paginate    = array(
        'fields'    =>  array(
                        'DISTINCT Contact.contact_id',
                        'Contact.first_name',
                        'Contact.last_name',
                        'Contact.email',
                        'Contact.created',
                        'ContactGroup.name',
                      ),  
        'conditions' => array(
                        $this->conditions,
                        'ContactsContactGroup.contact_group_id'=>$viewList,                        
                        isset($keywordQuery)?$keywordQuery:"",
                      ),      
        'limit'      => 5,
         'group'     => array('Contact.contact_id')
                      );
$data = $this->paginate('ContactsContactGroup');
$data = $this->paginate('ContactsContactGroup');
```

this query is called in every if and else statement, I have four conditions of `if` and `else`, and in all conditions the above piece of code is written.

I want to optimize, and avoid the big line of code in every condition, how can I optimize it, any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: If it is common for all the conditions than write above your if... else statements.

Comment: then how can I call pagination in that condition?

Comment: what exactly you are writing in if and else. can you provide some information on this..

Comment: these are my if and else statement if($viewList!=("all") && $viewList!=("dynamic") )  and }elseif($viewList=="dynamic" ){  the main difference is I add one more condition in pagination in elseif statement

Comment: you are using DISTINCT and GROUP BY for same field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the another method in your class that will return the array instead of posting it everywhere. Add the following code

```
private function getPaginate($viewList, $keywordQuery) {
  $this->paginate = array( 'fields' => array( 'DISTINCT Contact.contact_id', 'Contact.first_name', 'Contact.last_name', 'Contact.email', 'Contact.created', 'ContactGroup.name', ), 'conditions' => array( $this->conditions, 'ContactsContactGroup.contact_group_id'=>$viewList, isset($keywordQuery)?$keywordQuery:"", ), 'limit' => 5, 'group' => array('Contact.contact_id') );

  //optional: return the result
  return $this->paginate;
}
```

and then you can use

```
$this->getPaginate( $viewlist, $keywordQuery );
$data = $this->paginate('ContactsContactGroup'); 
$data = $this->paginate('ContactsContactGroup');
```

Comment: ah I see viewList has an uppercase L which I missed. Altered it

Answer (score 1):

What i use as regular practice on search page i keep adding condition in if and else and concatenate it at the end to the main query. In your condition i think we can do like below:

```
//here is your if and else statement
$condition = array();
if(someconditions) {
 $condition['user'] = 'suresh'; //your conditions
else if(some conditions)
 $condition['email'] ='abc@gmail.com';

//And than add it to main query 
$this->paginate    = array(
        'fields'    =>  array(
                        'DISTINCT Contact.contact_id',
                        'Contact.first_name',
                        'Contact.last_name',
                        'Contact.email',
                        'Contact.created',
                        'ContactGroup.name',
                      ),  
        'conditions' => array(
                        $condition
                        'ContactsContactGroup.contact_group_id'=>$viewList,                        
                        isset($keywordQuery)?$keywordQuery:"",
                      ),      
        'limit'      => 5,
         'group'     => array('Contact.contact_id')
                      );
$data = $this->paginate('ContactsContactGroup');
$data = $this->paginate('ContactsContactGroup');
```